# Safety of manipulating a value via a reference in a function

Tags: c++, reference, return

Simple question regarding style. Both the methods work (outlined below), I'm wondering which is considered better/safer practice?
I protect against integer overflow for adding, and have some functionality defined for removing. Both methods return the same results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
void safe_add(int&, int);
void safe_remove(int&, int);

int main() {
    int x = 50;
    safe_add(x, std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
    return 0;
}

/* 
 * Adds two integers while protecting against overflow.
 * int& target is manipulated directly in this function
 */
void safe_add(int& target, int amount) {
    if(target > 0 && amount > std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - target) {
        target = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    } else if(amount > 0) { //a pos int that won't cause an overflow!
        target += amount;
    }
}

/* 
 * Removes "amount" from "target". This function protects
 * against target becoming a negative.
 * int& target is manipulated directly in this function.
 */
void safe_remove(int& target, int amount) {
    if (amount > 0){
        if (target >= amount) { 
            target -= amount; //guaranteed >= 0
        }
        else if (target < amount) {
            target = 0; //simply remove the rest, i don't want negatives!
        }
    }
}
```

The second method simply returns the value of the calculation, and must be called to set the value of `x`, as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
int safe_add(int, int);
int safe_remove(int, int);

int main() {
    int x = 50;
    x = safe_add(x, std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
    return 0;
}

/* 
 * Returns the result of two integers added together,
 * while protecting against int overflow.
 * No parameters passed to this function are manipulated.
 * Instead, an int should be assigned the result of this function.
 */
int safe_add(int target, int amount) {
    if(target > 0 && amount > std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - target) {
        target = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    } else if(amount > 0) {
        target += amount;
    }
    return target;//not affected if given a negative
}

/* 
 * Returns the result of "target - amount"
 * The lowest value that target can be is 0.
 * No parameters passed to this function are manipulated.
 * Instead, an int should be assigned the result of this function.
 */
int safe_remove(int target, int amount) {
    if (amount > 0){
        if (target >= amount) {
            target -= amount;
        }
        else if (target < amount) {
            target = 0;
        }
    }
    return target; //not affected if given a negative
}
```

Can you break either one? Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: Define _'safe'_ more clearly.

Comment: `int destination=left; safe_add(destination,right);` as opposed to `int destination=safe_add(left,right);`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: These appear to be (buggy) saturating operations, to prevent accidental overflows.  Do you think there's another interpretation?  (There might be, but I don't see it)

Comment: Without getting pedantic, by "safe" I mean which is better in practice? If it's buggy, mind pointing out where, so I can fix it?

And yes, @MooingDuck, that's exactly what I mean. One cleaner than the other?

Comment: If you don't want negatives, consider using `unsigned int`; that makes your "safety" logic simpler too

Answer (score 0):

since you do not provide documentation/comments for your functions - from the POV of somebody just looking at the function as they are now, then the first method is more clear, the reference indicates that the argument can be modified. In the second case one is not really sure what is returned.

But this is just an opinion, you question cannot be answered in an objective way since "safe" means different to different people.

Personally I wouldn't put that much effort in doing it as you did, instead I would focus on using a data type with a well defined size from cstdint

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I'll add in some comments to make it more clear for future readers.

Thanks for the insight! :)